# How to pass Encoder object to constructor of a different class

Tags: class, pointer

I am trying to create a class (Arm) that controls an arm. The arms have 2 motors, each with an encoder, so I pass 4 integers for the pins and I am trying to pass 2 pointers (one for each encoder object).

the .ino file is:

```cpp
#include "Arm.h"
#include <Encoder.h>

//motor driver pins
#define ShoulderUP 7
#define ShoulderDW 8

#define ElbowUP 9
#define ElbowDW 10

#define encoderShoulderPinA 20
#define encoderShoulderPinB 21

#define encoderElbowPinA 22
#define encoderElbowPinB 23

//make encoder objects
Encoder ElbowEncoder(encoderElbowPinA, encoderElbowPinB);
Encoder ShoulderEncoder(encoderShoulderPinA, encoderShoulderPinB);

//make arm object
Arm Arm1(ShoulderUP, ShoulderDW, ElbowUP, ElbowDW, ElbowEncoder, ShoulderEncoder);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  Arm1.ShoulderMoveTime(1, 255, 1000);
}
```

the .h file is:

```cpp
#ifndef Arm_h
#define Arm_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Encoder.h>

class Arm {

public:
  Arm(int ShoulderUpPin, int ShoulderDownPin, int ElbowUpPin, int ElbowDownPin, Encoder *ElbowEncoder, Encoder *ShoulderEncoder);

  //pins connected to your encoder:
  //   Best Performance: both pins have interrupt capability
  //   Good Performance: only the first pin has interrupt capability
  //   Low Performance:  neither pin has interrupt capability

  void ShoulderMoveTime(int dir, int speed, int time);
  //dir = 0 means up, dir = 1 means down; speed between 0-255
  void ElbowMoveTime(int dir, int speed, int time);
  //dir = 0 means up, dir = 1 means down; speed between 0-255

  //Moves arm to poition given
  void ArmMovePosition(int shoulderPos, int elbowPos);

  // calibrates current arm position to zero
  void ZeroArm();

  //returns position of the arm
  void getArmPosition();

private:
  Encoder *ElbowEncoder;
  Encoder *ShoulderEncoder;
  int _ShoulderUpPin;
  int _ShoulderDownPin;
  int _ElbowUpPin;
  int _ElbowDownPin;
};

#endif
```

and the .cpp file is:

```cpp
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Encoder.h"
#include "Arm.h"

Arm::Arm(int ShoulderUpPin, int ShoulderDownPin, int ElbowUpPin, int ElbowDownPin, Encoder *ElbowEncoder, Encoder *ShoulderEncoder) {

  pinMode(ShoulderUpPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ShoulderDownPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ElbowUpPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ElbowDownPin, OUTPUT);

  _ShoulderUpPin = ShoulderUpPin;
  _ShoulderDownPin = ShoulderDownPin;
  _ElbowUpPin = ElbowUpPin;
  _ElbowDownPin = ElbowDownPin;
  //_ShoulderEncoderPinA = ShoulderEncoderPinA;
  //_ShoulderEncoderPinB = ShoulderEncoderPinB;
  //_ElbowEncoderPinA = ElbowEncoderPinA;
 // _ElbowEncoderPinB = ElbowEncoderPinB;
  ElbowEncoder = *ElbowEncoder;
  ShoulderEncoder = *ShoulderEncoder;
  //ElbowEncoder(_ElbowEncoderPinA, _ElbowEncoderPinB);
  //ShoulderEncoder(_ShoulderEncoderPinA, _ShoulderEncoderPinB);
}

void Arm::ShoulderMoveTime(int dir, int speed, int time) {
...
}

void Arm::ElbowMoveTime(int dir, int speed, int time) {
 ...
}

void Arm::ArmMovePosition(int shoulderPos, int elbowPos) {
  int ShoulderinitialPos = ShoulderEncoder.read();
  int ElbowinitialPos = ElbowEncoder.read();

  //TODO:I think this will only move one joint at a time

  //Move shoulder-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (shoulderPos > ShoulderinitialPos) {  //check to see which direction arm needs to move

    while (shoulderPos > ShoulderEncoder.read()) {  //while the target position is greater than the motor's actual position, move the shoulder up
      digitalWrite(_ShoulderUpPin, HIGH);           //THIS MAY BE REVERSED
    }
    digitalWrite(_ShoulderUpPin, LOW);  //stop the arm from moving up

  } else if (shoulderPos < ShoulderinitialPos) {

    while (shoulderPos < ShoulderEncoder.read()) {
      digitalWrite(_ShoulderDownPin, HIGH);
    }
    digitalWrite(_ShoulderDownPin, LOW);

  } else {
    Serial.print("Error: invalid shoulder target position");
  }

  //Move elbow-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  if (elbowPos > ElbowinitialPos) {  //check to see which direction arm needs to move

    while (elbowPos > ElbowEncoder.read()) {  //while the target position is greater than the motor's actual position, move the elbow up
      digitalWrite(_ElbowUpPin, HIGH);        //THIS MAY BE REVERSED
    }
    digitalWrite(_ElbowUpPin, LOW);  //stop the arm from moving up

  } else if (elbowPos < ElbowinitialPos) {

    while (elbowPos < ElbowEncoder.read()) {
      digitalWrite(_ElbowDownPin, HIGH);
    }
    digitalWrite(_ElbowDownPin, LOW);

  } else {
    Serial.print("Error: invalid elbow target position");
  }
}

void Arm::ZeroArm() {
  ShoulderEncoder.write(0);
  ElbowEncoder.write(0);
  Serial.println("Arm has been tared");
}

void Arm::getArmPosition() {
  Serial.print("Shoulder Position: ");
  Serial.print(ShoulderEncoder.read());
  Serial.print("Elbow Position: ");
  Serial.println(ElbowEncoder.read());
}
```

Unfortunately, there appears to be some sort of problem with passing the  Encoder object. I am getting the error:

> Compilation error: no matching function for call to 'Arm::Arm(int, int, int, int, Encoder&, Encoder&)'

I am definitely a noob when it comes to coding, so thanks in advance for what is probably a simple problem.

Comment: What happens when you pass the Encoder object as pointer via `&ElbowEncoder`?

Comment: I get "Compilation error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Encoder' and 'Encoder*')"

Comment: please copy all of the error message and paste it into your question ... **do not** put it into a comment like you just did ... also, **no pictures of text** ... format the text as code

Comment: you can use reference. member and parameter as `Encoder&` type and in _constructor initialization list_ you set the value of the member from the value of the parameter. `MyClass::MyClass(Encoder& _encoder) : encoder(_encoder) {}`

Answer (score 1):

You're jumping backwards and forwards between pointers and the objects themselves.
Change it to pass pointers to the arm constructor and consistently use pointers (or pass a reference and always use that, just be consistent). This would be something like:

```cpp
    // main code, pass a pointer rather than the object itself
    Arm Arm1(ShoulderUP, ShoulderDW, ElbowUP, ElbowDW, &ElbowEncoder, &ShoulderEncoder);

    // header
    public:
      Arm(int ShoulderUpPin, int ShoulderDownPin, int ElbowUpPin, int ElbowDownPin, Encoder *ElbowEncoder, Encoder *ShoulderEncoder);


    // cpp
    Arm::Arm(int ShoulderUpPin, int ShoulderDownPin, int ElbowUpPin, int ElbowDownPin, Encoder *ElbowEncoder, Encoder *ShoulderEncoder) {

      pinMode(ShoulderUpPin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ShoulderDownPin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ElbowUpPin, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(ElbowDownPin, OUTPUT);

      _ShoulderUpPin = ShoulderUpPin;
      _ShoulderDownPin = ShoulderDownPin;
      _ElbowUpPin = ElbowUpPin;
      _ElbowDownPin = ElbowDownPin;
      this.ElbowEncoder = ElbowEncoder; // use 'this.' to indicate the class private variable since it's the same name as the passed parameter.
      this.ShoulderEncoder = ShoulderEncoder;
    }
```

And then within your class, since ElbowEncoder is a pointer rather than the encoder itself, use `ElbowEncoder->method()` rather than `ElbowEncoder.method()`

Personally, I'd restructure it a little. Why create the encoders at the top level when they are only used within the arm class?
Create them in the arm class instead:

```cpp
    //in .h
    public:
      Arm(int ShoulderUpPin, int ShoulderDownPin, int ShoulderEncoderPinA,int ShoulderEncoderPinB,
          int ElbowUpPin, int ElbowDownPin, int ElbowEncoderPinA, int ElbowEncoderPinB);

    private:
      Encoder ShoulderEncoder;
      Encoder ElbowEncoder;


    // in .cpp
    Arm::Arm(int ShoulderUpPin, int ShoulderDownPin, int ShoulderEncoderPinA,int ShoulderEncoderPinB,
             int ElbowUpPin, int ElbowDownPin, int ElbowEncoderPinA, int ElbowEncoderPinB) :
                 ShoulderEncoder(ShoulderEncoderPinA,ShoulderEncoderPinB),
                 ElbowEncoder(ElbowEncoderPinA,ElbowEncoderPinB) {
       // constructor code
    }
```

This will create the encoders as private to the arm as soon as you call the arm constructor. Especially handy if you want to have more than one arm.